# $S_n$ acting on $\{1\;...\;n\}\times \{1\;...\;n\}$

Tags: finite-groups, proof-verification

> Let $X=\{1,\;...\;n\}$ and $S_n$ act transitively on $X\times X$ i.e.
>   $s:\;(m,n)\mapsto (s(m),s(n))$. Compute the orbits under this action.

*Attempt:* I claim that there are only two orbits, namely $\{(i,i),\;1\leq i\leq n\}$ and $\{(i,j):\;i\neq j,\;1\leq i,j\leq n\}$

Consider $(x,y),\;(a,b)\in X\times X$ where $x\neq y$ and $a\neq b$. If $x\neq a$ and $y\neq b$ take $s\in S_n$ where $s=(x\,a)(y\,b)$. We observe that $s:\;(x,y)\mapsto (a,b)$. Note that we can apply a second permutation to get to $(y,x),\;(x,a)$ or $(b,y)$. In other words any pair of distinct integers can be sent to any other pair of distinct integers.

Similarly for $s'=(x,a)$ we have $s':\;(x,x)\mapsto (a,a)$.

It is clear that $\text{orb} (x,y)$ and $\text{orb} (x,x)$ are disjoint for $x\neq y$ (since $(x,x)$ cannot possibly be sent to a pair of distinct integers) so we are done.

---

Have I correctly identified the orbits, and if so, is my justification correct?

Comment: You might want to check the cases when $s=(x\, a)(y\, b)$ are not disjoint cycles. This messes up some cases, such as $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ or $(x,y) \mapsto (y,z)$.

Comment: @blf Thanks, I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are proving is that the symmetric group is *two-transitive*, which means that for any pairs $(x, y), (z, w)$ _with $x\neq y, z\neq w$ there is an element of the symmetric group sending $x$ to $z$ and $y$ to $w.$ This is correct, and in fact the symmetric group is **six-transitive** (if $n$ is big enough) So, you are good.